# Writing symbol for representing the summation of n+1 items

Tags: math-mode

I know I can represent the summation of n items by writing $S_n$, but when I try to represent the summation of n+1 items by neither writing $S_n+1$ nor $S_(n+1)$ works.

Comment: Hi. Yo can try with `S_{n+1}`. With braces works for exponents too.

Comment: In TeX and LaTeX, curly braces -- `{` and `}` -- are the default grouping characters. Hence, `$S_{n+1}$` is what you should be writing.

Comment: There is a reason why the LaTeX manual *always* braces subscripts and superscripts. The *standard* way is to type `S_{n}`. With some experience, you'll learn when the braces can be omitted. Hint: try `R_\notin` to see that things can go wrong even when the subscript is “a single token”.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `S_n+1` Latex will recognise n as a subscript if you want to use `n+1` as a subscript then you will have to group them to group just type `S_{n+1}` in here latex will recognise n+1 as the subscript instead of n since you have grouped them.
So basically grouping combines n+1 as one string to be put in the subscript.
Put the grouped text in  `{}`.
Whenever you want to put more than one letter in the subscript or superscript use grouping!

Comment: Some would say even if you want to put *just one* letter in a sub- or superscript, you should group it.  While I do not follow such a convention religiously, it can certainly be argued as a "best practice".

Comment: Yes you are right I use it almost always